# Android Studio error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android-studio

One day, my Android Studio occur such error as below:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported annotation argument type: PsiBinaryExpression:-1.0 / 0.0
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.JavaAnnotationArgumentImpl$Factory.create(annotationArgumentsImpl.kt:47)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.JavaMethodImpl.getAnnotationParameterDefaultValue(JavaMethodImpl.java:65)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope.addAnnotationValueParameter(LazyJavaClassMemberScope.kt:678) ...
```

And then some kotlin class can not be recognized by Android Studio: no highline, wrong tips and so on...

Comment: So you already know the Question/Answer both. :D

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found the reason: Android Studio 3.3.0+ cannot recognize annotation `@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)`, then it throw error.

Just remove code `@FloatRange`, and then the problem disappeard

Comment: Hello, so how did you fixed it? Remove float range is not a sollution

Comment: I think it is an Android Studio bug. Yes, remove float range  annotation is not a good solution, but i can not find a better one.

Comment: Has someone filed a bug about this yet? It's really annoying to not be able to use autocomplete.